# Rule of three and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

`class A` defines copy operator, destructor and operator=. ([Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29))

If `B` inherits from `A`:

- the destructor will be called automatically
- I need to chain the constructor
- `operator=` ... should I define it explicitly for the class `B`?

Comment: With c++11, it is rule of 5 (move constructors)

Comment: @VJo: actually, you can leverage the copy constructor and move constructor and define a single assigment operator that takes its argument by value in lieu of defining two versions of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's unnecessary.

If you read carefully the Rule of Three, you will notice that nothing is said about a base class, the decision is made solely on the class proper attributes and behavior.

[(Check this example on ideone)](http://ideone.com/oId2t)

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A(): a(0) {}
  A& operator=(A const& rhs) { a = rhs.a; return *this; }
  int a;
};

struct B: A { B(): b(0) {} int b; };

int main() {
  B foo;
  foo.a = 1;
  foo.b = 2;

  B bar;
  bar = foo;

  std::cout << bar.a << " " << bar.b << "\n";
}

// Output: 1 2
```

This is actually the true power of **encapsulation**. Because you succeeded, using the *Rule of Three*, in making the behavior of the base class *sane*, its derived classes need not know whether the copy constructor is defaulted by the compiler or implemented manually (and complicated), all that matters for a user (and a derived class is a user), is that the copy constructor performs the copy.

The *Rule of Three* reminds us of an *implementation detail* to help achieve correct semantics. Like all implementation details, it matters only to the implementer and maintainer of this class.

Answer (score 2):

Same Rule of Three applies to the derived class as well.
The Rule is applicable to all classes and you can apply it to each class down an Inheritance hierarchy same as you apply it to a single class.

If your `class B` needs any of the two(**Copy Constructor & Destructor**) of the **Big Three** then you need to define the copy assignment operator as well.

So it actually depends on the members of the Derived class & the behavior you want for your Derived class objects.

For example:
If the derived class members consists of any pointer members and you need deep copies then as per the Rule of Three your derived class needs to overload and provide own implementations for the Big Three.

Comment: Why do you write 'If your class B needs any two...of the big three'? Doesn't the rule say if you need **one** of the three you'll need them all?

Comment: @nabulke: Ah well spotted,I actually meant, `any of the two` i missed typing `of the` which indeed changes the meaning completely.Thanks!

Comment: Also note that the *destructor* is a corner case, your class might not need a destructor and still need *copy-construction* and *assignment*. The simplest case is a class that holds memory thought a smart pointer, the default *destructor* will do what it needs, but you might still want to provide *value-semantics* by providing deep copying.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Yes I agree.Actually the point I wanted to put forward is Inheritance does not deter/defer in any way the Rule of Three(Five in C++11) is applied to an class.It just remains the same as while applying to a simple non-Inherited class.

Comment: Can the Downvoter enlighten with his/her views on downvoting this?Doing so will benefit us all mere mortals know what is wrong in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

> the destructor will be called automatically

It is still better to define the destructor in the derived class B, for consistency

> I need to chain the constructor

Of course. If the base constructor is default, it is still better for consistency.

> operator= ... should I define it explicitly for the class B?

Yes, something like this :

```
struct A
{
  A& operator=( const A & r )
  {
    // assign all A's member variables
    return *this;
  }
};

struct B : public A
{
  B& operator=( const B & r )
  {
    A::operator=( r );
    // assign all B's member variables
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Comment: A nice demonstration of when slicing is actually useful and used.

Comment: @KerrekSB: there is absolutely no slicing here, because `A::operator=` takes its argument by const reference.

Comment: I disagree, if the compiler is going to generate the correct operations for you, there is no point in generating them yourself and risking mistakes. Why would I define a destructor that does nothing? Why create a copy-constructor and assignment when they do the same as the compiler would do? I can give you a reason not to: *consistency*, if you add a new member to your type, the compiler will never forget to copy the field, but I have forgotten to add the new member to the copy constructor and assignment in types where they had to be manually defined. Advice: Be lazy, only work when *needed*.

Comment: (Note that the answer is a good example of *how* to do it if you *needed* to implement them in the derived type, but as Als pointed out, you only need to decide based on your type, and not that of your ancestors)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: well spoken

Comment: @MatthieuM.: You're calling `A::operator=(A const &)` with a `B` object; isn't that slicing? `A`'s operator assigns the sliced subobject, while `B`'s operator does the rest.

Comment: @KerrekSB: as far as I am concerned, slicing occurs when creating a copy of a part of an object. More informally, I would not tag this regular behavior as slicing because slicing usually refer to a misuse.

Answer (score 1):

What Als says is correct, but i am not sure he answers your question. If there is nothing specific that you want to do in B, besides what you're already doing in A's big three, then there is no reason why you should define B's big three as well.

If you do need one of them though, the rule of three should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code and the output:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
 int a;
 public:
 A():a(0){}
 A(A const & obj){std::cout << "CC called\n"; a = obj.a;}
 A & operator =(A & a){std::cout << "operator= called\n"; return a;}
 ~A(){std::cout << "A::dtor called\n";}
};

class B: public A{
};

int main(){ 
 B b,v;
 b=v;
}
```

Output:

```
operator= called
A::dtor called
A::dtor called
```

Comment: You misunderstand the Q.The OP is not asking for any code,S/He is asking help on making a decision whether the derived class needs to apply Rule Of Three if Base class applies it.